# How to load /import outlook custom form programatically using outlook plugin

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, addin-express

According to the following image custom outlook form (.oft) file can be import.
  is there way of doing it using outlook plugin programatically ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom forms are not used with COM add-ins. That is entirely separate and old technology. Mostly admins deploy custom forms with code behind to organizations.

If you need to customize the Outlook UI from COM add-ins you may consider using Outlook form regions. The `CompleteReplacement` layout allows to replace the whole window UI or create your own custom one. See [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019) for more information. Note, you may even load old form regions designed in Outlook.